# How to format new HDD windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, installation, formatting

I just bought new SATA 1TB Baracuda HDD, I inserted and my windows didn't recognize it. Because I didn't have any other OS or anything to format it I used Centos i386 installation to format it. I of course disconnected my original disk from the motherboard and formatted it using CENTOS.. but now when I come back to the windows I can't format this HDD. Its recognized as RAW. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This belongs on superuser.

You need to create a filesystem.  Go to "Start" -> "Run" -> enter "compmgmt.msc" and create a partition using "Disk Management."

Comment: @Warner It does probably but I'll accept your answer anyways cause its valid. thank you